# Relink google form to spreadsheet fires onSubmit event for all records

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with google form linked with spreadsheet that has onSubmit trigger. If I unlink form from it's spreadsheet and then link it again with the same spreadsheet google engine creates new sheet and (!) fires onSubmit trigger for all responses that already exist! I discovered it because my onSubmit function creates some spreadsheet based on the answers.
Is it a expected behavior of this mechanism or it just an issue? 
P.S.
I've tried to delete onSubmit trigger before create a new link, but it doesn't help:

```
  delete_onsubmit_trigger();
  Logger.log('triggers deleted');
  //Utilities.sleep(2000); //here I think that perhaps trigger deletion takes some time, but it doesn't help either
  set_destination_to_form(form, ss);
  set_onsubmit_trigger(ss);
```

functinons codes are:

```
function delete_onsubmit_trigger() {
  delete_trigger('onSubmit');
}

function delete_trigger(name) {
 var triggers, handler;
 triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
 for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
   handler = triggers[i].getHandlerFunction();
   if (handler == name) ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
 }
}

function set_destination_to_form(form, ss) {
  form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
}
function set_onsubmit_trigger(ss) {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onSubmit")
     .forSpreadsheet(ss)
     .onFormSubmit()
     .create();
}
```

Any ideas how to bypass this suddenness?

Comment: Search the Issue Tracker.  [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)